# Random SSH IP from China

Tags: networking, server, ssh, iptables

My nas server running ubuntu-server 19 has the 22 port open for remote access and I was just casually looking at netstat when I noticed a strange IP. Turns out it's from china and when I looked it up, a site said that it's high threat or whatever. Should I be worried about it?

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 asus-nas:microsoft-ds   192.168.0.122:63312     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 asus-nas:9091           192.168.0.122:64566     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 asus-nas:40268          secondary.danava.c:http TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      1 asus-nas:ssh            14.29.130.153:53454     LAST_ACK
tcp        0      0 asus-nas:9091           192.168.0.122:64519     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 asus-nas:9091           192.168.0.122:64520     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 asus-nas:ssh            192.168.0.122:62102     ESTABLISHED
```

The `192.168.0.122` IP is my computer I'm accessing the server from.

Comment: Is your authentication keys-only? Password auth has been disabled?

Comment: @user535733 nope, I'm using password auth

Comment: Then they probably guessed the password: You have no idea what backdoors they installed. Take your system offline immediately, wipe it clean, and reinstall Ubuntu...and install key-based-only authentication. Data that is not backed-up is already gone - you cannot trust it anymore. Wipe it.

Comment: @user535733 well s**t

Comment: My first learning-server got owned the same way - dictionary attack. I was fortunate - lost nothing important and learned a valuable lesson. The *feeling of intrusion* can be worse than the actual data loss. Sorry. Good security is a *set of habits* that we cultivate: Backups. Keys. Checks for unusual activity. Layers. Tests. And keeping notes on exactly what we did so we can maintain it or rebuild it.

Comment: @user535733 fortunately this was a day old install and nothing was on it so nothing got lost, I reinstalled it and the first thing was to set up the key auth so I hope I'm safe now.

Comment: FYI:  there is no Ubuntu server 19; Ubuntu desktop and server releases use *yy.mm* format (year.month), with only specialist releases using *yy* (and they only come out in even years; eg. Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances). If you're talking 19.04, be aware it's EOL so re-install a supported release (and consider LTS releases if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.

Comment: You should get antivirus if the ip comes from the wuhan region. Just kidding.

Comment: @КристиянКацаров :'D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have disabled password login and use ssh keys there is no need to be worried.

SSH is constantly beeing tried from all around the world...

If you like you can install & configure fail2ban to automatically add blocking rules to your iptables

Comment: Can you throw me a link to a good tutorial on how to set up ssh keys please? I'm still using password auth

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: @user535733 Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

However... I use *OpenVPN,* with one-of-a-kind digital certificates and its `tls-auth` feature, to *completely shut down(!)* all "unauthorized access attempts" to my `ssh` layer.

To get to any of my systems, you must possess a non-revoked 4096-bit certificate, which has been issued only to you.  Only one user at a time is allowed to use the same certificate.  And, to even *see that an OpenVPN server exists(!),* you must also have a `tls-auth` credential. *(In this way, the OpenVPN server effortlessly deflects attempts to pester it and to waste its CPU-time:  it knows that it can simply ignore them.)*

All certificates issued to "road warriors" are encrypted with passwords which must be provided to allow them to be used.  *(This is to buy us the necessary half-hour of time we need to **revoke** the unique certificate that was on the stolen laptop, thereby rendering it permanently useless.)*

`sshd` listens only to addresses that are insde the OpenVPN outer-moat and is of course firewalled away from ever *[accidentally ...]* attempting to do otherwise.  Simply open the tunnel and *then* you can use `ssh`.

**Number of unauthorized access attempts: *Zero.***

I compare this to the "Dwarvish doors" of *Lord of the Rings.*  If you possess the proper keys, you can swiftly and easily enter.  Otherwise, you see a smooth cliff face and cannot discern that a portal is there.

Comment: P.S. I wrote about this topic here:  https://www.sundialservices.com/essays/number-unauthorized-access-attempts-zero/